# Creating a custom MySQL function?

Tags: php, mysql, function

I've just started using MySQL with PHP and I'd like to know if it's possible to create a custom function. This code snippet should illustrate what I'm trying to do.

```
// a somewhat complicated formula not suitable to embed into the query
function Distance($latA, $lonA, $latB, $lonB)
{
  // earth's radius
  $radius = 3956;

  $latA = deg2rad($latA);
  $lonA = deg2rad($lonA);
  $latB = deg2rad($latB);
  $lonB = deg2rad($lonB);

  // calculate deltas
  $deltaLat = $latB - $latA;
  $deltaLon = $lonB - $lonA;

  // calculate Great Circle distance
  $result = pow(sin($deltaLatitude / 2.0), 2) + (cos($latA) * cos($latB) * pow(sin($deltaLon / 2.0), 2));
  $distance = $radius * 2 * atan2(sqrt($result), sqrt(1 - $result));

  return $distance;
}

// how can I call Distance() in my query?
$query = "SELECT lat, lon FROM zipcodes WHERE Distance(lat, lon, 0, 0) < 20";
mysql_query($query);
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Just FYI, you can do that perfectly find from a query. In fact, if you use a spatial index based on your lat/lngs and you will find that the results are impressive. Incredible infact.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, could you please elaborate on this? Also by "unsuitable" I didn't mean in terms of performance (I know nothing about that); I meant how painfully long the query would be.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You an declare this MySQL function in your application, and it will remain in the database until the database server is restarted.

```
mysql_query("CREATE FUNCTION Distance(LAT_A INT, LON_A INT, LAT_B INT, LON_B INT, )
RETURNS INT
READS SQL DATA
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE radius, deltaLat, deltaLon, result, distance BIGINT;
SET radius=3956;
SET deltaLat=LAT_B-LAT_A;
SET deltaLon=LON_B-LON_A;
SET result=POW(SIN(deltaLat/2), 2) + (COS(LAT_A) * COS(LAT_B) * POW(SIN(deltaLon/2.0), 2));
SET distance=radius * 2 * ATAN2(SQRT(result), SQRT(1 - result));
RETURN distance;
END");
```

This uses MySQL's [mathematical functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html). Offloading this processing to the database is fast and efficient (the data doesn't have to travel across the wire, and you're only returned the results you want).

Once you've declared this, you can use it like so:

```
$query = "SELECT lat, lon FROM zipcodes WHERE Distance(lat, lon, 0, 0) < 20";
mysql_query($query);
```

However if your database does restart, any functions or procedures declared previously are lost. It's possible to handle MySQL error 1305 (`Function functionName does not exist`) gracefully at the application level.

In your database error handler:

```
switch (mysql_errno()):
    case 1305:
        if (false === $database->_declareStoredProcedureFlag) {
             if ($c = preg_match_all("/FUNCTION [a-zA-Z0-9]+\." .
                 "([a-zA-Z0-9_]*) does not exist/is",
                 mysql_error(), $matches)
             ) {
                 $storedFunctionName = $matches[1][0];
                 $database->_declareStoredProcedureFlag = true;
                 if (true === $database->declareStoredFunction($storedFunctionName)) {
                     $result = mysql_query($query);
                 }
             }
         }
         break;
    ...
```

Comment: Is this the only option? I'd rather keep it confined to PHP at the moment. I'll wait another few minutes to mark an answer.

Comment: yeh I guess it's not happening. I'm going to go with this, +1. Cheers mate.

Comment: Because you are using the values `lat` and `lon` in the `Distance()` function call in the query, and these come from the database, the only other option is to select the whole dataset (containing those values) from the table into PHP, run it through the PHP version of the function and essentially run number-crunching (which databases are designed to perform efficiently) in PHP (which is significantly slower). You then have the added overhead of transferring the data from the database to PHP. This is the optimum solution, but obviously adds complexity.

Comment: This actually works surprisingly well once you have created the function. Does this mean that in the case that my database server crashes, when rebooting, I should run that `CREATE FUNCTION ..` query again?

Comment: @Jonathan answer updated for graceful handling of errors in case of server reboot.

Comment: But that means the function would have to still be stored right?

Comment: Yes, the function has to be declared on the database server to run. If that code is in `$database->declareStoredFunction()`, you can start the server without the function, make a query (that fails), respond to the error (by creating the function) and re-run the query - all transparently.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can write a MySQL function to do this.  I don't have time to write one now, but here's where you get started:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: Oops I thought you wanted to take your php function and make it into a MySQL function.  Sorry!

Comment: There was another answer that showed how to call the function using ". function_ame()." syntax which is also doable if you want to keep your function in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql has stored routines http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html

Some of the functions may be different, for example, the mysql equivalent to php's deg2rad is mysql's radians() function.  I think you should be able to create an equivalent function.  With this approach, You should be aware that these queries will have to tablescan the entire zipcodes table every time however.

Answer (score 0):

Because functions don't work in quotes " or ' you have to split it up with a full stop. (.)

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT lat, lon FROM zipcodes WHERE ".Distance($lat, $lon, 0, 0)." < 20");
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: As @thedaian stated above, this will not work as `lat` and `lon` are variables in the SELECT statement.